# Read line by line and insert data ( 16 GB JSON) too slow ( MySQL + JAVA spring boot )

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, read-write, zstd

I have B2B2C business and I have few suppliers who keep update my data.
Every week I need to update around 30GB JSON ( one file ).
I would like to know about faster way than readline of BufferedReader the file type is ZStandard(zstd).
For now its inserting 500Mb every 4 hours.
is that make any sense that is so slow ??
the web app and database are deploying on unix server ( Tomcat apache 9.06)

my code :

```
    try {
        BufferedReader br;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/opt/tomcat/" + fileName));

        String line = br.readLine();

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

        while (line != null) {
            

            if (!rootRepository.existsByAddress(om.readValue(line, Data.class).getAddress())) {
                rootRepository.save(om.readValue(line, Data.class));
            }

            line = br.readLine();
        }

        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Completed";


}`
```

Comment: Have you tried batching multiple lines together?

Comment: every line is different object , I cannot batching them.

Comment: I would guess that your bottleneck is in the two database calls (`existsByAddress` and `save`). [g00se's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710608/read-line-by-line-and-insert-data-16-gb-json-too-slow-mysql-java-spring-b?noredirect=1#comment121430169_68710608)  suggests batching the inserts like in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update).

Comment: Collect 100 objects, then batch insert all 100 in a single `INSERT`.

Comment: ok , the batch is working well but still very very slow after 2 GB...